# How to Blur Div Edges

Tags: css, html

Using CSS,

like the following:
http://gyazo.com/ff14a415cf7ac8622eb0cada3e23137f

I want to us CSS (preferably not CSS3) to get the edges and corners to have that effect, instead of just sharp egdes.

Comment: That is an image (unless you are saying that is strictly an example of the look you want).  If you want to do something similar to that, you would have to look up gradient borders with CSS, though it would be easier to use box-shadow or an image

Answer (score 47):

You can achieve this effect by using a `box-shadow` the same color as the div's background, like this:

```
.blur-box {
    background-color: #555;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 10px #555;
}
```

You can adjust the second and third arguments (`5px` and `10px` here) to tweak the relative size and blur radius (respectively) of the shadow in order to get it the way you want, and this feature is well supported by modern browsers (see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow).

Here's a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bXAFt/

Comment: Anyway to do that with original CSS and not CSS3?

Comment: @OP CSS3 is part of CSS. You're better off telling us which browsers you want to support. Old IE has filters that can be used as a fallback.

Comment: @JamesMitchell: your effect is unachievable with CSS <3. You should really care about modern browsers in concerns of design, while writing your site to support graceful degradation/progressive enhancement.

Comment: "CSS3" is a (somewhat) definitive specification, but whether browsers support it is on a feature-by-feature basis. http://caniuse.com/ is a good way to check which features are available in your target browsers.

Comment: I guess when your background is gradient or an image you have a problem?